# Laravel route pass variable to controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

How do I pass a hard coded variable to a controller?

My route is:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => $locale), function() {
    Route::get('/milk', array('as' => 'milk', 'uses' => 'ProductsController@index'));
});
```

I want to do something like:

```
Route::get('/milk', array('as' => 'milk', 'uses' => 'ProductsController@index(1)'));
```

But that doesn't work.

How can this be done?

---

Sorry if I have not explained well.

I wish to simply hardcode (set in stone by me) the type_id for certain routes like so:

```
Route::get('/milk', array('as' => 'milk', 'uses' => 'ProductsController@index(1)'));
Route::get('/cheese', array('as' => 'cheese', 'uses' => 'ProductsController@index(2)'));
...
```

My ProductsController for reference:

```
class ProductsController extends BaseController {

    public function index($type_id) {
        $Products = new Products;
        $products = $Products->where('type_id', $type_id)->get();
        return View::make('products.products', array('products' => $products));
    }

}
```

Comment: Where does the value come from? If it is always the same, you can add it as a private property in your controller.

Comment: @Jerodev It is hard coded into the routes. e.g. milk is 1, orange juice is 2, bicuits is 3 etc. This is so I can have SEO friendly names really otherwise it would be easy i.e. Route::get('/product/{id}.....

Comment: Do these values come from the database? If so, can't you find the id of the products in your controller?

Comment: @Jerodev For these static routes no they don't.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use a closure for your route and then call the controller action:

```
Route::get('/milk', array('as' => 'milk', function(){
    return App::make('ProductsController')->index(1);
}));
```

However, a nicer way would be to use a `where` condition and then do the type-to-id conversion in the controller. You will lose the direct alias though and would have to pass in the product as parameter when generating the URL.

```
Route::get('{product}', array('as' => 'product', 'uses' => 'ProductsController@index'))
    ->where('product', '(milk|cheese)');
```

Answer (score 4):

I have used this to pass values to the controller...

route:

```
Route::get('user/{user}/usermanage',  array('as' => 'userdata.usermanage',       'uses' => 'yourController@getUserDetails'));
//{user} - holds some value...
```

in controller:

```
public function getUserDetails($id)
{
    ...
}
```

if want dynamic :

```
$var    =   "Lists"; 

Route::get('something',        array('as' => 'something',      'uses' => 'yourController@get'.$var));
```

hope this helps...

Comment: Works for Lumen as well. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

I feel like the tidiest way to do this is probably with [route constraints](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-parameters):

```
Route::get('{milk}', [ 'as' => 'milk', 'uses' => 'ProductsController@index' ])
     ->where('milk', 'milk'); // matches the named arg {milk} (param 1)
                              // to the regex literal 'milk' (param 2)
```

It has some redundancy, but if you want to do it purely from your routes, I'd go with this.

For making SEO-friendly names though, you could use [Sluggable](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable) to generate a unique slug for each product, then create the following route:

```
Route::get('{product}', [ 'as' => 'product', 'before' => 'product-slug', 'uses' => 'ProductsController@index' ])
     ->where('product', '[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9\-]*'); // valid slug syntax
```

And this filter:

```
Route::filter('product-slug', function($route) {
    $slug = $route->getParameter( 'slug' );
    if (is_numeric($slug)) { // if the slug is an ID
        $product = Product::findOrFail($slug); // try to find the product
        return Redirect::route('product', $product->slug); // and redirect to it
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you actually do it without messing up the url:

Define Route:

```
Route::match(['GET', 'POST'], 'my-url', ['var_1'=>'hello', 'var_2'=>'world', 'prefix'=>'my-prefix', 'middleware'=>['web', 'mid2', 'mid3'], 'as'=>"my-route-name", 'uses'=>'myController@index']);
```

Now in the controller, inside `function __construct(Request $request)`:

```
$req_action = @$request->route()->getAction();

$var_1 = $var_2 = '';
if(is_array($req_action) && !empty($req_action['var_1'])){
$var_1 = (int)@$req_action['var_1'];
}

if(is_array($req_action) && !empty($req_action['var_2'])){
$var_2 = @$req_action['var_2'];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Sorry you're all wrong...

```
Route::GET('/url-name', function(Request $request){

    // Pass in custom SEO DATA
    $seo = [
        'title' => 'Hello world',
        'description' => 'some Description'

    ];

     $c = new \App\Http\Controllers\MyController();
     return $c->index($request, $seo);
});
```

In the controller....

```
public function index(Request $request, $seo = null)
    {

        dd($seo);
}
```

Comment: Hello, and Welcome to Stackoverflow. Actually your way is one unrecommended way of doing it, though it achieves the result. But if your controller needs some dependency injection in the constructor, you won't be able to auto resolve it.  `App::make()` is your best friend in this case.. That's being said, consider addressing people using a nicer way other than "You're all wrong".